# How can I set a function's cell position by a cell value (templating/string expression)

Tags: google-sheets

I'd like to have something like:

```
  A   B   C
1 5   1   *expression here*
2 3
3
```

C's expression:

```
= `A(B1)` - A2 // would translate to: A1 - A2 which is 2
```

Where B1 Holds the row number for the C column.
I know this is quite funky, but I had to ask.
(If stackoverflow isn't the right fit for this question, please let me know)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
=indirect("A"&B1)-A2
```

in C1

Dragging down works as I would expect, I assume you want to drag across? If so, This might do what you want. If not, can you provide an example?

```
=A1-offset(A1,1,0)
```

Comment: It is really close, but I want A to be "dynamic" so if I drag it out on several cells they will take the right offset in relation to them, is that possible?